# String is a class so should it be by reference?

Tags: c#

From the below code(First way) my output is "11".
and the Second way output is "1199";
But as String is a class, it should be by reference and (First way) should return "1199";
Why is it not working that way?

```
//First way:
void StringTest()
{
    String s = "11";
    Update(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

void Update(String v)
{
    v += "99";
}

//Second way:
void StringTest()
{
    String s = "11";
    Update(ref s);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

void Update(ref String v)
{
    v += "99";
}
```

Comment: Strings may seem to behave like value types at times but that's for two reasons. Firstly, String is the only reference type that supports literals. Secondly, Strings are immutable. When you think you're modifying a String, you're not. You're actually creating a new String object. That's like using a constructor for another reference type. If you view it in that light, you can see that Strings act just like any other reference type.

Comment: It's not "by reference". You are passing that parameter by value. That means that assigning a new object to the parameter in the method, which you're doing, cannot be reflected in the original variable. That's exactly the same as any other reference type. Being a reference type is different to paying by reference. Reference types can be passed by value or by reference and value types can be passed by value or by reference.

Comment: The `ref` keyword has nothing to do with reference types (i.e., classes), and is completely unrelated to reference types. It works equally with value types. Try your example with `int` instead of strings, for example, you will see the exact same behavior despite no reference types being involved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first snippet:

```cs
void Update(String v)
{
    v += "99";
}
```

As a result of `+=` a new string will be created and assigned to the local variable, the fact that `string` is a reference type does not mean much here.

Also note that `string`'s are [immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#immutability-of-strings) in C#:

> String objects are immutable: they can't be changed after they've been created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object.

Comment: Indeed. The difference is between `v.Append("99")` (which works for StringBuilder, but not for String, and actually modifies `v` in-place) and `v = v + "99"`, which is basically a succinct way to write `v = string.Concat(v, new string("99"))`.